# Ball-Line Collision Bounce Angles Python

Tags: python, vector, line, collision

I'm writing a program wherein the user creates lines (represented as (x1,y1,x2,y2)) that balls subject to gravity bounce off . These lines are therefor not necessarily horizontal. I've been having trouble with getting the correct bounce angles. I found sources that provided a good method but in order to use it I need to find the line's bounce angle.

Obviously there are two possible normal vectors but I need the one that faces towards the side of the ball collision. The only problem is that I need to use Tkinter in my program and because of the timestep my collision detection works in a way that sometimes lets the ball dip slightly past the line before the collision is detected. So I can't just use the center of the ball (cx, cy) to determine the correct normal vector. I'm probably overcomplicating this in my head, but I'm having trouble coming up with a solution. I think it needs to involve the incident velocity vector (vx, vy) of the ball on collision, but I'm not sure how.

Any ideas would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The correct normal vector to use is the one such that `n scalar v = n.x v.x + n.y v.y` is negative. Indeed, scalar product is positive when two vectors are globally in the same direction. So wanting it to be negative means you will have two opposite-pointing vectors, which is exactly what you want.

However, you cannot define such a normal vector on angles, so I do not know how you programmed your algorithm but be careful with this edge case.

Comment: I think I phrased it poorly. My lines are not necessarily horizontal. But they are straight. Is this what you meant by a normal vector on angles?

Comment: Well, if the ball hits this way: `O->     ------` ; then your normal vector for the line in the collision context is mathematically undefined.

Comment: And how exactly would I go about getting BOTH normal vectors?

Comment: Yes! I was going to create a different function for the case of collision with the line endpoints.